# Computing linear gradients by section so as to mimic the effect of a larger one

Tags: qml, linear-gradients

Here is my issue. I need a see through hole (square one) in my application. The problem is that my real application contains a gradient over its entire background. To simulate this problem I've written a MWE.

In order to create the hole, I need to create 4 rectangles that I will fill with the proper gradient so as to simulate the over all gradient shown in the code.

Like so:

[image]

I'm asking for help on how to write the gradient description in each of the rectangles (1 through 4) so that they would look exactly the same as they do in the picture which is showing 1 big gradient.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

ApplicationWindow {

    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Render Server Development Helper App")
    color: "transparent"


    Rectangle {

        id: mainRect
        anchors.fill: parent

        LinearGradient {
            anchors.fill: parent
            start: Qt.point(0, 0)
            end: Qt.point(width,height)
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#ff0000" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.034; color: "#ff0000" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.7792; color: "#0000ff" }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#0000ff" }
            }
        }

        Column {

            id: buttonRow
            width: 0.1*parent.width
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top

            Button {
                id: btnConnect
                hoverEnabled: false;
                width: parent.width
                text: "CONNECT"
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("Connecting ....");
                }
            }

        }

        Rectangle {
            id: frame
            width: parent.width*0.7;
            height: parent.height*0.8;
            border.color: "#000000";
            border.width: 5;
            //anchors.centerIn: renderServerView
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color: "transparent"
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the same approach as we discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74034165/qml-is-it-possible-to-have-a-transparent-rectangle-in-an-no-transparent-window) and avoid complicated gradient stitching.

Be aware that translucent windows only work on systems that have compositing enabled. Have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#creating-translucent-windows).

### Canvas

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: "transparent"

    Canvas {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")

            var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, root.width, root.height)
            gradient.addColorStop(0.0, "red")
            gradient.addColorStop(1.0, "blue")

            ctx.fillStyle = gradient

            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, root.width, root.height)
            ctx.fill()

            ctx.clearRect(220, 140, 200, 200)
        }
    }
}
```

---

### OpacityMask

```
import QtQuick
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "transparent"

    LinearGradient {
        id: bg
        visible: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        start: Qt.point(0, 0)
        end: Qt.point(root.width, root.height)
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "red" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "blue" }
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: cutout
        visible: false
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            width: 200
            height: 200
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: bg
        source: bg
        maskSource: cutout
        invert: true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I never saw your comment in your original question!!! This is Fing A!!! Thank you. I was just about to use a canvas to compute the gradient myself to ensure consistenty but this is BEAUTIFUL: Os in the product is By definition Windows 10. Always. So composition will not be an issue. THANK YOU!

Comment: @aarelovich I think it is best practice to use `OpacityMask` with the `Invert` attribute set to true. `Canvas` is quite slow if you plan to resize the window. (*Another alternative is to use simply ShaderEffect*)

Comment: To be honest I'm trying to code so that the application can never be resized. Worst casa minimized. The computer will ONLY be used fro running this applicatiion. It is a very special use case. Can you provide some example code of how I can accomplish the same thing with either the OpacityMask or the Shader Effect?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a solution using `OpacityMask`. `ShaderEffects` on the other hand is just too complicated in Qt6 to properly set up due to all of the `.qsb` magic. If you want to dive into this topic here are two links to get you started. [Qt Shader Tools Build System Integration](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtshadertools-build.html) [Qt Quick Examples - Shader Effects](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.4/qtquick-shadereffects-example.html)

Comment: @aarelovich I apologize for missing your comment; the new answer is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Thank you again for everyone with the answes!