# Custom shaped window with title bar in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'd like to implement a window with a transparent background in the middle part :

[image]

I can achieve the translucency with [setMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindow.html#setMask) and `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground | Qt.FramelessWindowHint` flags but I lose the title bar :

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    flags: Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
}
```

```
auto window = getWindow();
QRegion mask;
mask += QRegion(0, 0, window->width(), 100);
mask += QRegion(0, 280, window->width(), 200);
window->setMask(mask);
```

[image]

If I remove `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` then I get the title bar back but lose the translucency:

[image]

And even if removing `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` plays well with translucency, it will bring the side borders back and that's not something I want.

How can I achieve the design in the initial picture ? I'd like to avoid implementing a custom title bar if possible.

I also tried creating 2 windows and binding the bottom window to the top one as follows :

```
window2.x: window1.x
window2.y: window1.y + some_space
```

But the result was not satisfactory due to the lag while moving the windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74048097/computing-linear-gradients-by-section-so-as-to-mimic-the-effect-of-a-larger-one/74048325#74048325

Answer (score 2):

Using the code from my comment above this would be my solution. I don't know about the side borders that you mentioned in your question.

```
import QtQuick
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "transparent"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "white"
        visible: false
    }

    Item {
        id: cutout
        visible: false
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            height: 200
        }
    }

    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: background
        source: background
        maskSource: cutout
        invert: true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! That's a better approach than mine however it doesn't work unless I add Qt.FramelessWindowHint flag to my window. I'm on MAC, I see you're on a different platform. I guess it's a platform dependent issue.

Comment: It actually says that transluceny will not work without Qt.FramelessWindowHint on MAC so I guess I have no other option than implementing a custom title bar.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#creating-translucent-windows